# MySQL autoincrement increasing by more than +1 per record

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, create-table

I'm planning a database design for an online store and having an issue with the customer table. I've set a PK and I'm testing by inputting some dummy data. Problem is that when I insert a new row it's not autoincrementing with +1 but more a case of 2,5,7 on the ID.

SQL is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foundation`.`Customer`
( `CustomerID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CustomerFirstName` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `CustomerLastName` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `CustomerUsername` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `CustomerPassword` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
  `CustomerEmail` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `CustomerEmailVerified` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  `CustomerRegisteredDate` DATETIME NULL,
  `CustomerActive` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  `CustomerNewsletterSubscribed` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  `CustomerDescription` TEXT NULL,
  `CustomerType_CustomerTypeID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `Username_UNIQUE` (`CustomerUsername` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Customer_CustomerType1_idx` (`CustomerType_CustomerTypeID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Customer_CustomerType1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerType_CustomerTypeID`)
  REFERENCES `foundation`.`CustomerType` (`CustomerTypeID`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: show your insert query

Comment: I'm inserting the dummy data via SQL pro. It's a GUI for Mysql db's

Comment: Are you sure you are not passing id from you code?

Comment: Positive - All fields appear NULL until I input into them. Once I submit it adds the ID

Comment: When you run `Last_Insert_ID()` what do you get? This should give you your auto incr value post-insert. You say it's more of a random schema `"2, 5, 7"`, but let's make sure. [See the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: I get a last insert id of 0, Assuming I need to insert some data??

Comment: I tried a quick fix, apparently removing the autoincrement, saving & then adding it back fixed the issue - thanks

Comment: You should keep in mind that AUTO_INCREMENT does **not** guarantee consecutive generated id's. If you need your id's to be consecutive you need to find another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following system variable, auto_increment_increment it should be 1. If not then it'll increment by the value in it.

show variable like '%auto_increment%'

Also check if you are incrementing manually in the insert query.